# How to handle a global variable when Navigating between pages ? (C++/CX XAML)

Tags: xaml, navigation, c++-cx

Trying to reproduce [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=angQoWwGWxw&list=PLi2hbezQRVS0cPMeW3uDlUHnO_rPvJCV9&index=19) c# XAML tutorial sample in c++/cx XAML.
Go to [this exact](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=angQoWwGWxw&list=PLi2hbezQRVS0cPMeW3uDlUHnO_rPvJCV9&index=19#t=17m2s) place in the video to see why we add the global variable.

Here how i declare my variable "someImportantValue":

```
namespace NewMultiPages
{
    ref class App sealed
    {
    protected:
        virtual void OnLaunched(Windows::ApplicationModel::Activation::LaunchActivatedEventArgs^ e) override;

    internal:
        App();
        static Platform::String ^someImportantValue;

    private:
        void OnSuspending(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::ApplicationModel::SuspendingEventArgs^ e);
        void OnNavigationFailed(Platform::Object ^sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::Navigation::NavigationFailedEventArgs ^e);
    };
}
```

here the code in page2, where i click the button to go to the page3:

```
void NewMultiPages::Page2::HyperlinkButton_Click(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    App::someImportantValue = ValueTextBox->Text;
    this->Frame->Navigate(Page3::typeid, ValueTextBox->Text);
}
```

when compiling i get this error:

Erreur  LNK2001 symbole externe non résolu "public: static class Platform::String ^ NewMultiPages::App::someImportantValue" (?someImportantValue@App@NewMultiPages@@2P$AAVString@Platform@@$AA) NewMultiPages   C:\Users\lr\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\NewMultiPages\NewMultiPages\Page2.xaml.obj    1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what are the access specifics of static fields on ref classes, but if you remove the static modifier from the field - you can access it this way:

```
static_cast<App^>(App::Current)->someImportantValue = ValueTextBox->Text;
```

Comment: That seems to work, but how safe is that ?  what exactly does the ::current do ?  is it multi thread safe ?

Comment: `Current` returns the current `App` instance. Not sure how it behaves when called from another thread or if you have multiple windows. Then again - storing important values in `App`, while most common - is also probably the worst approach. You should define your own classes with different responsibilities, that are unit-testable and preferably not using C++/CX. :)

Comment: what's wrong with c+/cx ?  I tought you need that if you want to do UWP in c++  ?

Comment: You need it to interface with the WinRT type, but for anything else you can still use pure C++. C++/CX is awesome for interfacing with WinRT, but it's not without some problems. C++/WinRT attempts to address some of them, but for any app-side data structure and logic that doesn't have to live in WinRT-derived classes - it might be better to use the standard C++.